# Cannot enable "Save and fill payment methods" in chrome settings

Tags: google-chrome

I am signed into my google account in chrome and have all of the settings syncing, but for some reason, I cannot enable the "Save and fill payment methods" setting (or the "Always verify when using autofill").  It just shows as disabled and greyed out.  This is only for 1 computer and this particular google account.  The same account on a different computer's chrome works fine, i.e. the setting is enabled and can be toggled.  Similarly, other profiles on this computer also work fine, i.e. the settings are all enabled and toggle-able.
I've tried restarting the browser and the machine, but neither help change that setting or make it enabled for me to toggle.

How can I re-enable this setting? [image]

Comment: The simplest explanation is that your password manager -- Bitwarden -- is influencing this, which makes sense, it will want to manage the auto-filling for you.  Since this question is not about programming, it should be moved to something like superuser.

Comment: @tresf That does seems to be it.  I guess I have different settings for bitwarden on the other computer.  Put this as a response so that I can mark it as the answer.  Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: Were you able to confirm that disabling Bitwarden actually does bring that toggle back?  I don't use Bitwarden, so I was unable to test this theory, which is why I was hesitant to provide it as an answer.